# Laravel Filename includes Backslashes also with stripslashes

Tags: php, sql, laravel, mariadb

I have got a the following problem:
I have create a simple Image Upload Process like this.

```
public function postImage($id){
    $filename = date('Y-m-d_H:i:s').".jpg";
    $note=Note::find($id);
    $destinationPath='/srv/www/htdocs/example.com/api/public/projects/'.$note->project_id.'/notes/'.$id."/images/";
    $file = Request::file('image');
    $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
    $image = new Image;
    $image->filename='projects/'.$note->project_id."/notes/images/".$filename;
    $image->note_id=$id;
    $image->save();
    $result= $this->respondWithItem($image, new ImageTransformer);
    return $result;
}
```

When returning filename which is in this case path to file beginning from projects plus  at the end the filename it always returns
something like that `projects\/1\/notes\/images\/2015-03-27_10:44:291.jpg`
I of course dont want to have backslashes in my response.

I use a Transformer for that like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Image;
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;

class ImageTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{

public function transform(Image $image)
{
    return [
        'id'              => (int) $image->id,
        'filename'           => $image->filename,
        'note_id'            => $image->note_id,
        'updated_at'      => strtotime((string)$image->updated_at),
        'created_at'      => strtotime((string)$image->created_at)
    ];
}
}
```

I tried everything from `str_replace` to `stripslashes` on the filename but it did not work. Am I missing something I am doing wrong?
When returning just the filename directly in the controller the response is correct.

Comment: How the filename look like in database? with or without backslashes?

Comment: The database has saved them without backslashes. We use MariaDB